# Error response from daemon: Mount denied - Error got while running docker application, which was working last night

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Suddenly my `docker run` stopped working last night, which was working before. `docker build` is working fine, but I get the below error when trying to run the container.

**Command**

```
 docker run -it --rm -p 9001:4200 -v ${pwd}/src:/app/src angularclient
```

**Error message**

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: Mount denied: The source path
>   "E:/Karthik/angular/src" doesn't exist and is not known to Docker. See
>   'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

I tried running the following command in the power shell:

- `refreshenv`
- `set MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`
- `set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

Comment: Check in your docker settings if E: is defined as a shared drive.

Comment: Yes it is shared

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 9001:4200 -v E:/Karthik/angular/src:/app/src angularclient
```

It seems that you can't use `${pwd}` and `./` on win cmd and Git Bash. You can only use absolute paths.

Comment: I tried it is not working, it is not throwing error, but when i make changes the changes are not reflecting

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

Comment: Can you add some explanations please? What is the aim of this command? 
And your answer seems to be for unix no?

Answer (score 0):

Add / to prefix of path as below.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 9001:4200 -v /${pwd}/src:/app/src angularclient
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the drive is shared in Docker settings "Shared Drives".
2. Create the full path if it doesn't already exist.
3. Add trailing `/` to the path.